# Help with specific Python re application

Tags: python, regex, parsing

folks,
I am working on using Python re to parse a configuration file that contains lines like this:
    [VAR: abc123]
    ...
    
    ...

```
.CSIIND~~~LOCAL~~~I4~~~0~~~

[VAR: def234]
...
<bunch of stuff>
...
```

.CSIIND~~~LOCAL~~~I4~~~1~~~

...

I'm trying to build up to extracting something like this:

varname / CSIIND

abc123 / 0

def234 / 1

...  ...

I don't have a lot of regex background, so I'm probably a bit slow on this, but I've been seeking out every tutorial and resource I can find, to no avail.

Please help me, at least with directional suggestions! I don't mean to ask for finished code!

The farthest I have gotten is this regex:

r"^[VAR:.+?].+?CSIIND",

which at least matches as many times as I expect it to, but I can't get it to match the number

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Also please add more examples of input and the output you'd want from it

Comment: Please format your code properly!

Comment: I thought I had by indenting 4 spaces as the "ask question" form instructed.

Comment: Try out your regex interactively with re-try: http://re-try.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Need more detail.  Is the variable the "var" the thing enclosed in square brackets?  With the name before the ":" and the value everything after?
[foo:"Mr Bar's Foo shop"]

If so, you might just be able to split on the ":" rather than bothering with a complex regex.

Ok look at this:

```
import re
stuff0='[stuff:junk]'
stuff1=stuff0[1:-1]            # Knock off the brackets
stuff2=re.split(':', stuff)    # Split the name from value 
stuff3=stuff2[0]+'/'+stuff2[1] # Recombine into your requested format 
print stuff3
'stuff/junk'
```

I split that out into many lines for clarity.  You could pull several steps into one line.

Comment: Thanks, Skip, however what I really want to extract is more like: junk / 1, junk2 / 2 junk3 / 0

Comment: Doug that is a pretty trivial change over what I gave.  Do you want a string in the format you describe?  Just initialise the string before looping through the file {stuffstring = ''} then append each line item to it as you go {stuffstring += stuff3}.  Or you could build a dictionary with it {dictionary[stuff2[0]] = stuff2[2] or just about whatever you need.  What are you eventually trying to do with the data?

Comment: Skip: really, thanks for the effort and help. I am planning to feed the data to a spreadsheet, so ultimately am likely to land on CSV output for this.  I've been thinking, too, that a dictionary based approach might be a better approach to this. I appreciate the help from everyone, even though it didn't really answer the question as asked; it was more of a rework of my entire approach. Thus, I still hope to figure out the regex one day even if I go in another direction for now.

Comment: regex is a really powerful tool.  I use them a lot.  My whiteboard often features "Don't Fear The Regex"  But they are a tool that isn't needed in all cases, they make code harder to read and slower to write. I mostly use them in two cases, when they make my code more efficient, and when they make my code more understandable. If you are going out to a spreadsheet, you might want to look at the csv module, included in the standard library, since it may do most of what you need in a clear fashion.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Oh, and one other note, you might want to "accept" one of answers given as the best for your question.  It is kind of how this site works.  One person asks a question, others offer answers, and the original person "accepts" the one that fits best.  Just click the checkmark on the left of the answer you want to accept.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more than you asked for:

```
ch = '''[VAR: abc123]
hhhgfgfjhfghjf
... ...
.CSIIND~~~LOCAL~~~I4~~~0~~~
[VAR: def234]
...
<bunch of stuff>
...
......
.CSIIND~~~LOCAL~~~I4~~~1~~~
llhgjgj
[VAR: ab1587]
hhhgfgfjhfghjf
... ...
.Cosoo~~~LOCAL~~~I4~~~120~~~
zhbyi,i,uy_o
[VAR: abc123]
hhhgfgfjhfghjf
... ...
.CUSUT~~~LOCAL~~~I4~~~28~~~
[VAR: def234]
...
<bunch of stuff>
...
......
.CUSUT~~~LOCAL~~~I4~~~45~~~'''

import re
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

RE = ('\[([^:]+):\s+([^\]]+)\]\s*[\r\n]+'
      '(?:.+[\r\n]+)*?'
      '\.([^~\r\n]+?)~~~[^~]+~~~[^~]+~~~(\d+)~~~')

pat = re.compile(RE,re.MULTILINE)

li =  [ (k,[tuple(x)[1::2] for x in g]) for k,g in groupby(pat.findall(ch),key=itemgetter(2))]
for y in li:
        print y
```

result

```
('CSIIND', [('abc123', '0'), ('def234', '1')])
('Cosoo', [('ab1587', '120')])
('CUSUT', [('abc123', '28'), ('def234', '45')])
```

From **li**, you can deduct any presentation you want

Comment: @Doug Will there be only one varname in the configuration files analysed, as **CSIIND** in your exemple ? If so, my code is doing too much and I can simplify my code I you wish. If not (that is to say several varnames in one file, like **CSIIND**,**Cosoo**,**CUSUT** in my exemple) do you want me to explain my code ?

Comment: There are a couple of dozen parameters for each.